# How to form an interrogative possessive sentence?

Tags: sentence

> **A.** *Do you have a car*?

Or

> **B.** *Have you a car?*

I always use the first form of the sentence but I noticed that the second one is also used. Which is correct?

Comment: I'm going to say A is American, B is British, but I'm A so I can't speak exactly for B.

Comment: @HowardPautz I'm B and can say it's hardly ever used.

Comment: @AndrewLeach and both A & B can say it is certainly duplicated :-O

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct.
For this sentence, you could also use :  "Have you got a car ?".